# Objective-C KVO doesn't work with C unions

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing, unions

I need to observe union-typed properties on an Objective-C class using KVO, but it seems I have no luck with this. I did some experiments: everything works fine as long as I am using a C struct. As soon as I replace the struct with a union, automatic KVO doesn't work anymore (`observeValueForKeyPath` is not being called).

Here's my small test class:

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

typedef union {
    float data[3];
    struct {
        float x,y,z;
    };
} vec3union;

typedef struct {
    float x,y,z;
} vec3struct;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (assign) vec3struct vectorStructValue;

@property (assign) vec3union vectorUnionValue;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize vectorStructValue = _vectorStructValue;
@synthesize vectorUnionValue = _vectorUnionValue;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"vectorStructValue" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"vectorUnionValue" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    self.vectorStructValue = (vec3struct){1,2,3};
    self.vectorUnionValue = (vec3union){4,5,6};
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"keyPath %@ did change, object: %@", keyPath, [object description]);
}

@end
```

Output:

```
2013-01-12 17:38:26.447 KVOTest[57522:303] keyPath vectorStructValue did change, object: <AppDelegate: 0x100614200>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug or missing feature in the Objective-C runtime/KVO implementation?

Note: I know I can implement this manually, by overriding the property setter, but this is not the point of this question. The answer should give me an idea of why the automatic KVO doesn't work in this case.

**Update**: Just to make this clear, this is a simple test case comparing the KVO observer on a struct property to that on a union property. These properties are *not interrelated*. They have independent ivars with independent memory backing stores. You can remove the struct property and run the test, still the same result – no KVO observer event for the union property.

Comment: Or better yet, be explicit about your change to the value (`willChangeValueForKey:`, `didChangeValueForKey:`);

Comment: The memory layout shouldn't play a role for the assignment/KVO mechanism. Even if the value of the union wouldn't be correct there the observer should be called. Manually issuing the change via `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` works when overriding `valueForKey:` and returning a manually generated `NSValue` from the union bytes. However, this is not subject of the question.

Comment: It doesn't work with 'observeValueForKeyPath:' but all OK with 'didChangeValueForKey:'. Strange.

Comment: In my actual app I got an exception in `didChangeValueForKey:` when not overriding `valueForKey:` and returning a manually constructed `NSValue` object.

Comment: Wow, an actual SSCCE! I haven't seen one of those around here in a dog's age. I see the same results; this is an interesting find.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The properties aren't related in OP's question.

I misread that in a fever induced hallucination.

Unions are just flat out busted in KVO/KVC.  Leaving the text below because it is still interesting.

---

KVO doesn't work by watching memory or playing any such tricky shenanigans like that.  It works by dynamically creating a subclass on the fly, overriding the setter method, and invoking the `willChange.../didChange...` methods automatically when the setter is called.

Thus, you effectively have *2 properties* with *1 backing* store.  As far as KVO is concerned, though, they are in total isolation from each other.

What you want is dependent keys.   You can use [`+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to create a dependency between the two keys such that calling either setter will trigger a change for the other property.

I don't know if it supports co-dependnence;  if it supports what would effectively be a circular dependency.

Alternatively, you ought to be able to override the setter to call `willChange/didChange` for the other property (as well as the property being changed).

---

The related keys would be used if you want `willChange/didChange` to fire for *both* keys if *either property changes*.  I.e. if you muck with the struct, the union effectively changes and observers of the union property should see a will/did change in response to setting the struct version.

I just tested it.  You're right.  Something is odd with unions.  It is flat out broken.  All of the above still remains true, but it does no good.

Radar filed: rdar://problem/13003794

---

Oooh... neat.  KVO w/unions simply doesn't work.  It appears that the runtime simply does not even recognize that the class has a key called `vectorUnionValue` at all.

I added:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingVectorStructValue
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"vectorUnionValue"];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingVectorUnionValue
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"vectorStructValue"];
}
```

Which caused a runtime exception:

```
2013-01-12 12:05:11.877 djkdfjkdfjkdf[51598:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<AppDelegate 0x10010a520> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key vectorUnionValue.'
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct. Why should there be just one backing store? Actually you can remove the struct property, it was just for clarification in my example. It doesn't change anything about the fact that the automatic KVO implementation doesn't work for the union property. As for the willChange/didChange implementation: I am aware that I can do it manually, the question is why doesn't it work automatically (as it should)?

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but I still don't see how this should be related to dependent keys, multiple properties and the number of backing stores. Also, I did not make the point that KVO would do some magical memory watching.. Would be great if you could clarify this, so I can consider accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I won't accept this answer even if 10 more people are going to upvote it. The idea that the properties are somehow interrelated is plain wrong. Perhaps I should change the example in the question so that it doesn't contain the struct property anymore. Just to get this down to the point that the question really only is about the obviously defunct KVO on the union property.